# Star rating not showing in Google

Tags: google-search-console, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I've had this problem for 2 weeks. Google is not showing the star rating of my post in searches, although in the test snippets tool it's showing correctly. Google is also crawling the richsnippets‎ values since I specifically fetch a post with the Google Web Master Tool and check the values.

Here is what it looks like in Google snippet tool result:

[image: In Google snippet tool result]

and what it currently looks like on Google:
[image: on Google]

I'm using the  GD star rating plugin (1.9.22) and Wordpress (3.5.1).

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I got the same problem GD Star Rating 1.9.22 and Wordpress 3.5

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in Webmaster tools under Search Appearance > Structured Data

It will list any data there that it considers important. It is worth noting that they tend to be a bti funny about reviews, if you have less than 10 reviews don't expect anything to show. Also structured data is notoriously up and down, it isn't and exact science so maybe give it a little longer.

Comment: Thanks tim , but my reviews are more than 10 and its been more than one that its not showing in Google.
Any other option please?

Answer (score 0):

I am also searching on it ,
and I found on google below link,

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#aggregate_ratings

Ratings

An aggregate evaluation of an item by many people should be marked up as a schema.org/AggregateRating . The default rating scale is from 1 (worst) to 5 (best), but any scale can be used; see below for an example. ***Google MAY display aggregate ratings as rich snippets or, for certain types of items, answers in search results, as shown below.***